# Missing vulkan extension: VK_KHR_storage_buffer_storage_class

Tags: driver, pi-400

[According to Igalia](https://blogs.igalia.com/itoral/2021/08/10/an-update-on-feature-progress-for-v3dv/) the [v3dv driver](https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/v3d.html) should have the extension.

But `vulkaninfo` on an rpi-400 only reports back with these extensions:

```
Device Extensions: count = 5
----------------------------
        VK_EXT_external_memory_dma_buf : extension revision 1
        VK_KHR_external_memory         : extension revision 1
        VK_KHR_external_memory_fd      : extension revision 1
        VK_KHR_maintenance1            : extension revision 2
        VK_KHR_swapchain               : extension revision 68
```

Any reason why an up-to-date raspberrypi OS installation would lack the `VK_KHR_storage_buffer_storage_class` extension?

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: bcm2711-hdmi0 driver: vc4_hdmi v: N/A 
           Device-2: bcm2711-hdmi1 driver: vc4_hdmi v: N/A 
           Device-3: bcm2711-vc5 driver: vc4_drm v: N/A 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev resolution: 1280x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: V3D 4.2 v: 2.1 Mesa 20.3.5
```